# Laravel Adding Class Name Dynamically

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Here is my

```
{{ Form::text("Article[$i]", $interfacedetload->ArticleNo, array('class'=>'my_prs_inp1 free_enter1','id' => "Article$i")) }}
```

Which produces

```
<input class="my_prs_inp1 free_enter1" id="Article2" name="Article[2]" type="text" value="1" style="display: inline-block;">
```

And so on.. in For Each loop

In the above code i am generating name and id dynamically after `Article[x]`

That is working good, But How can i add the class name dynamically

i.e.,

```
class="my_prs_inp1 free_enter[$i]"
```

So the class name should be

```
class="my_prs_inp1 free_enter1"
class="my_prs_inp1 free_enter2"
class="my_prs_inp1 free_enter3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try by this way

```
{{ Form::text("Article[$i]", $interfacedetload->ArticleNo, array('class'=>"my_prs_inp1 free_enter{$i}",'id' => "Article$i")) }}
```

Comment: It just prints <input class="my_prs_inp1 free_enter{$i}" id="Article3" name="Article[3]" type="text" value="1">

Comment: It works fine for me, I think you checked class name with single quotes 'my_prs_inp1 free_enter{$i}'